# filtering and though a sharepoint list items with powershell

Tags: 2007, powershell

I have tried below but not getting any result back
Not sure if i'm doing this well.
Can i filter in the foreach or in my if statement
Thanks in advance

```
[DateTime] $CreatedDate = $item["Created"] 
$convertedCreatedDate = $CreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")


foreach ($item in $list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today}) {

if ($list.items | where {$convertedCreatedDate -eq $today}) 
{

Write-Host $item["Created"] 


}

Write-Host $item["Created"] 

}
```

Comment: C'mmon guys no one can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can filter in either or both the foreach statement and/or the if statement. You don't define $list in your question so I can only guess at what you're shooting for. It looks like you're trying to select items created in the last day from the collection in $list.Items. If so, this should get that job done:

```
$list.Items | 
    where { ([DateTime]::Now - [DateTime]$item["Created"]).TotalDays -lt 1 }
```

To perform some operation on each of those returned items add a foreach to the end of the pipeline:

```
$list.Items | 
    where { ([DateTime]::Now - [DateTime]$item["Created"]).TotalDays -lt 1 }
    foreach {
        # do something with $_ here
    }
```

Update your question with how you define $list and I'll verify my answer if necessary.